# How to rewrite an initializer in Swift for a subclass

Tags: swift

Suppose that i have a class with default `init()` inside.

```
class Car { 
    var tires: Int
    var doors: Int
    init (tires: Int, doors: Int){
        self.tires = tires
        self.doors = doors 
    }
}
```

Then i am creating a subclass - BMW for example.
BMW subclass will have its own unique variable for engine volume.

```
class BMW: Car {
    var volume: Int
    -------- type code here---------
}
```

I want to use **init()** of parent class, then add to that **init()** my  **volume** variable, so that when i create an instance of **subclass BMW**, code will be like:

```
var newCar = BMW(tires: Int, doors: Int, volume: Int)
```

Note*: I do not want to hardcode any Value in subclass itself(using super.init()), i want to create totally new initializer.

Is it possible? If yes, could you please assist me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First initialize the `volume` property of the subclass, then call the designated initializer of the `super` class

```
class BMW: Car {
    var volume: Int

    init(tires: Int, doors: Int, volume: Int) {
        self.volume = volume
        super.init(tires: tires, doors: doors)
    }
}
```

Please read Swift [Language Guide: Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) and [Inheritance](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html)

Comment: So it means that, if a have a parent class with like 20 different properties like doors, tires, volume, speed and etc, and i want to generate a subclass and add 1 more, i have to duplicate  a code. I thought there will be better way.

Comment: It's not really a duplication. You need the two `init` and `super.init` lines and one additional line for each individual property in the subclass. That's the way inheritance works in Swift.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I though there would be a way not typing properties every time if i want to create a new init for each subclass, so that  subclass will inherit parent init and connect with its own init by using some keyword.So it looks like, there is no way and i have do it manually for each subclass. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a new initializer. Ideally, this should call up to the initializer you created for the Car class, using `super.init(tires:doors:)`.

```
init(tires: Int, doors: Int, volume: Int) {
    self.volume = volume
    super.init(tires: tires, doors: doors)
}
```